# C++ - Converting a char to wchar_t. Getting a segfault

Tags: c++, casting, char, istream, wchar-t

I'm trying to write small program that reads in a character from an istream and converts it to a wchar_t. I'm getting a segfault. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

wchar_t read(istream &stream) {
 char *c;
 stream.read(c, sizeof(*c));
 cout << *c << endl;
 wchar_t retChar = static_cast<wchar_t>(*c);
 return retChar;
}

int main() {
 cout << "Write something" << endl;    
 read(cin);
}
```

My logic here is:

1. Create an array of chars because read only takes arrays of chars.
2. Read in bytes equal to the size of a character. i.e. read a character and store it in the array c.
3. Create a wchar_t and cast that character *c into a wchar_t.
4. return wchar_t

Since I'm getting a segfault, there's obviously something wrong here. I can't see it though. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks SO

Comment: You never allocate memory for your `char*`. Than you are not really converting anything - you just casting types without any converstion.

Comment: Your segfault isn't related to conversion to `wchar_t`. You are getting because of first 2 lines of your `read` function. You are reading into an unitialized (invalid) pointer (not to mention - dereferencing said pointer in the same line.

Comment: Also you can declare what you want to have the thing stored into and then cast that to a `char*` in the call to `read`.

Comment: You did not create an array of chars anywhere.

Comment: Also why not just open the file with a `wifstream` and reads the data into a `wstring`?

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't believe I was overlooking something so simple. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @NathanOliver. I don't want to read into a string. I only want to read one character at a time.

Comment: OK.  Then use a `wifstream` and a `wchar_t` and `operator >>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through the code to give OP a look at what's going on and why it won't work. Then we'll take a look at a method to do what they want that is as close as possible to their intent. Then a hint on how to do this a bit better in the C++ world.

```
wchar_t read(istream &stream) {
 char *c;
```

Declares a pointer `c` and doesn't point it at anything. `c` is an uninitialized variable. Think of it like being invited to Steve's house for a party, but no one told you where he lived. Odds are very good that where ever you go, it won't be Steve's house.

```
 stream.read(c, sizeof(*c));
```

`sizeof(*c)` will return the size of one character. Probably 8 bits and 1 byte, but `c` still hasn't been pointed at anything so this is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There is no telling what the program will do, but most likely it reads one byte into some unknown space in memory. Maybe this causes a crash because you can't write there. Maybe it writes over something that it is allowed to write over and screws up something else.

```
 cout << *c << endl;
```

Tries to print out `c`. If the program survived the `read` above, odds are good it will survive this as well, but this is also Undefined Behaviour.

```
 wchar_t retChar = static_cast<wchar_t>(*c);
```

This will literally stuff one character's worth of data into a wide character. It will not convert it according to locale or any other character encoding. `char` is a numeric code that has been defined to be interpreted as a character.  A cast will stupidly put the character value, say 'A' and ASCII encoding into `retChar`. `retChar` now equals 65. 65 could mean anything depending on the encoding used by `wchar_t`. It might still mean 'A', but sorry Ayn Rand, this is one case where A may well not be A.

```
 return retChar;
}
```

To do what OP was trying to do (and ignoring that there are better ways to do this for the time being):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
wchar_t read(istream &stream) {
 char c[2];
```

Allocates an array of characters. Why? because the easiest way I know of is to do the conversion on a string.

```
 stream.read(c, sizeof(c[0]));
```

`c` is now an array which decays to a pointer. We only want to read one `char`, so `sizeof(c[0])` gets the size of the first element in the array.

```
 c[1] = '\0';
 cout << c << endl;
```

Null terminate and print.

```
 wchar_t retChar[2];
```

Again, an array.

```
 mbstowcs(retChar, c, 1);
```

convert one character from char to wide char using whatever locale has been set.  Read more on locales here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

And documentation on mbstowcs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs

```
 return retChar[0];
}
```

Put all together with a quick tester:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

wchar_t read(std::istream &stream)
{
    char c[2];
    stream.read(c, sizeof(c[0]));
    c[1] = '\0';
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    wchar_t retChar[2];
    mbstowcs(retChar, c, 1);
    return retChar[0];
}

int main()
{
    std::wcout << read(std::cin) << std::endl;
}
```

This is simple, but ugly in the C++ world where you should stick to `string`s where possible. [In that case look into std::wstring_convert.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert)